# ObjectInputStream readObject() in a File

Tags: android, ios

My Android app is requesting through a HTTP POST command a download request. This download is a MultiPart session sending JSONObjects and File (Image).

but when I'm trying to retrieve the File from:

```
            ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(con.getInputStream());
            File p = new File(path, o.photo_id+".png");
            p.canWrite();
            p = (File) objIn.readObject();
```

My file p is getting a 0 length...
as I'm not familiar with InpuStream/OutputStream I don't know exactly how to write my File physically in memory....and first to retrieve it !
any idea is more than welcome !

Comment: Just to complete my question...Server shall be able to send JSONObject and images to either Android and IOS devices, so not sure the File object is suitable. if you have any advice for the type of object I need to send.... thanks

Comment: How does your Json file/data looks like? Does it have the image's bytes or just a link to the image? Write an example here

Comment: no my JSONObject is independent from my File. JSONObject is only containing String content, and server is sending two parts, first the JSONObject and second the File. But I think you answered my question....I can include the picture in a Byte Array into the JSONObject instead of sending the File separately....Hence I'm sure IOS platforms may be able to read it as well.....am I right ?

Comment: Read bytes? Of course